# Why is CKEditor adding itself to divs where it is not supposed to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a page where I've initialized Bootstrap-WYSIWYG and CKEditor together.

The problem is CKEditor keeps adding itself to Bootstrap-WYSIWYG div even though I've specifically initialized CKEditor using `class="ckeditor"`

My code is as follows:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

The page can be found at http://cloudadmin-theme.elasticbeanstalk.com/rich_text_editors.html

Try clicking on the tab that says **"Bootstrap Editor with Keyboard Shortcuts"** where it's written **"Go ahead..."**. This brings up CKEditor onfocus, which is weird!

I'm at my wits end. Can someone kindly guide me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: minified javascripts does not help to understand the issue. Where do you instantiate ckeditor??

Comment: Oops, sorry. I didn't instantiate ckeditor. I've used their default init procedure that asks for class="ckeditor" to be added to the textarea where CKEditor is desired.

Comment: it is the automatic inline mode for elemets with contenteditable="true"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

CKEDITOR by default will auto hook up elements that have the `contenteditable="true"` attribute. You want to turn off the [CKEDITOR's auto inline editing](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-disableAutoInline) or it can be done in the global config.

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```

I prefer to do it in code and not in the config so if anyone else uses it, you do not screw them up.

---

Based on your comment on enabling CKEDITOR [*This is pulled from the CKEDITOR 4 docs*](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline)

> **Enabling Inline Editing**
>
> Inline Editing is enabled directly on HTML elements through the HTML5
>   contenteditable attribute.
>
> Suppose, for example, that you want to make a  element editable.
>   In order to achieve this, it is enough to do so:
>
> ```
> <div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
>     <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
>     <p>The div element that contains this text is now editable.
> </div>
> ```
>
> It is also possible to enable editing with explicit code, by calling
>   the CKEDITOR.inline method:
>
> ```
> <div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
>     <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
>     <p>The div element that contains this text is now editable.
> </div>
> <script>
>     // Turn off automatic editor creation first.
>     CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
>     CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable' );
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked like a charm. Btw, @giammin is right too, what can we do about that? Can we enable it for individual elements through code?

Comment: Yes you manually call the elements you want to be editors just like it says in the docs: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline

Comment: Just some info for anyone else stumbling across this... I am using CKEditor 4.3.2, and putting `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;` in the `config.js` file does not appear to have any effect. But if I put that in a `<script>` element in the web page it does work.

Comment: Scott Mitchell's comment solved my problem and save my time :)

Answer (score 4):

What you are experiencing is the ckeditor [inline editor mode](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline).

It is automatically instantiated when you have an html element with:

```
contenteditable="true"
```

To avoid it you can remove this attribute or you can put in /Ckeditor/config.js file

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```

To bind ckeditor in [standard mode](http://ckeditor.com/demo#standard) you can use:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
```

If you want to bind it in [inline mode](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline):

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor1' );
```