# Can I disable CKeditor initializing on elements with contenteditable=true?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

It seems that CKeditor automatically initializes on any element that has `contenteditable=true`. It even says so on [their Guides page](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_ckeditor_js_load.html#inline-editing), but with no instructions on whether this can be avoided.

This makes me lose a lot of control over the content on my page. I have some content that should be editable with the rich text editor, and some other that shouldn't. But this makes CKeditor initialize on elements that don't even expect rich text, and they don't get saved as rich text in the database... So I need to get rid of it from the interface, but I don't know how...

Can I tell it to avoid automatic initialization?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is CKEditor adding itself to divs where it is not supposed to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073472/why-is-ckeditor-adding-itself-to-divs-where-it-is-not-supposed-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is `No`.

The alternate solution, is to omit the `contenteditable=true`, then after initializing the CKEDITOR, set the `contenteditable` attribute on the required element from Javascript.

Comment: 2024: above answer is outdated, check the answer given by @joshuahedlund

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```

(See [this answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073472/why-is-ckeditor-adding-itself-to-divs-where-it-is-not-supposed-to))

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Added this right after the script reference and it works fine.

Comment: working solution in 2024